# Determination of the day of the week

Tags: c#

I have to implement a Interface that returns the next weekday date after the date passed in. I need to use this code:

```
DiaryDate nextWeekday(DiaryDate originalDate);

public DiaryDate(int dayOfMonth, int monthOfYear, int year)
{
    DayOfMonth = dayOfMonth;
    MonthOfYear = monthOfYear;
    Year = year;
}
public int DayOfMonth
{
    get;
    set;
}
public int MonthOfYear
{
    get;
    set;
}
public int Year
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Is there a formula for working out which date will be a week day?

Comment: Do you need to take holidays, etc. into account ?

Comment: Not really sure about your question, why not `DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)`, that would give you the next date ??? Or do you want to check if it is not Saturday/Sunday

Comment: Construct a `DateTime` object and add 1 day while you have `Saturday` or `Sunday`. Then take the current day of the week at that time. If it doesn't loop you have your current day, if it does loop it will get you a monday. Or really just check if today is saturday/sunday. If yes: take monday, else take today.

Comment: date.dateofweek maybe?

Comment: @Habib, he wants the next weekday (i.e., not Saturday or Sunday)

Answer (score 2):

I'll just copy from my comment:

> Construct a DateTime object and add 1 day while you have Saturday or Sunday. Then take the current day of the week at that time. If it doesn't loop you have your current day, if it does loop it will get you a monday. Or really just check if today is saturday/sunday. If yes: take monday, else take today

```
var someDate = new DateTime(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth).AddDays(1);
if(someDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || someDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) { 
    return DayOfWeek.Monday; 
} else { 
    return someDate.DayOfWeek; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert the object into a `DateTime` to get access to all of the tools available through them:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(originalDate.Year, originalDate.Month, originalDate.Day);
```

Then we can just add a day and then keep adding days while the date is a weekend:

```
date = date.AddDays(1);
while (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday ||
    date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
{
    date = date.AddDays(1);
}
```

Then all you need to do is convert it back into your own date object, assuming you can't change your code to use `DateTime` instead.

Comment: Hi sorry guys this a homework assignment I don't think I am allowed to use date objects etc will probably have to use a formula like "Zeller'scongruence"                                                                                                               http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence

Comment: Then I suggest you make an attempt at implementing that. Next time mention it in your question as well, we had no way of knowing.